# How do I quit swift repl without using ctrl-d?

Tags: swift, read-eval-print-loop

I want to quit swift repl gracefully and not use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> to exit it.

For eg. python repl can be exited by typing `exit()`. Is there a similar way of quitting swift repl?

Comment: Just so you know, ⌃D _is_ graceful (it's EOF). It's ⌃C that's not.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

*This answer complements Ankit Goel's correct `:quit` answer to also (1) provide an understanding of why the `:` is needed and (2) other options besides `:quit`.*

Swift REPL works in conjuction with the LLDB debugger.

`:` is a REPL escape prefix to execute an LLDB command. From within REPL, `:help` will list the available LLDB commands.

Any of the following will quit both Swift REPL and subsequently LLDB with a single command line.

```sh
:exit
:quit
:q
```

One can also exit REPL into LLDB with just `:` and, then later `quit` (or `exit`) using the LLDB command directly.

```sh
sh$ swift
  Welcome…
1> print(18 + 4)
  22
2> :
(lldb) print "hello"
  (String) $R0 = "hello"
(lldb) quit
sh$
```

Addendum: The LLDB command `c` or `continue` can be used to return to the Swift REPL environment.

Comment: You can also type Control-D into the LLDB prompt to get back to the Swift REPL.

Answer (score 15):

Just found out that a graceful way to quit swift repl is by using typing `:quit`

It does not work without the colon.

Comment: You got robbed!

Comment: Your answer is earlier. You should have marked your own as accepted. Then all those upvotes might have come to you :)

Comment: Hmmm... I was simply thinking to provide an informative answer … to a question with no accepted answer at that time. I did upvote this answer prior to adding my response. Likewise, others may also upvote this answer ... and the question, if they so wish.