# What are the differences between xcodebuild, xcrun and swift command line tools?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, xcodebuild

We can build and run Swift code/projects from the command line via multiple commands without using Xcode. I have heard of `xcodebuild`, `xcrun` and `swift` used for Xcode development. I do use `fastlane` but I don't really understand the tools powering it under the hood.

I am an iOS developer who uses a Mac. I develop using Xcode so I haven't used these command-line tools before.

What are the differences between each command? Are there any cases where I'd be better off using one over the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Tl;DR

`xcodebuild` and `xcrun` help build Xcode projects in a headless context, for example in CI setups. `swift` is the Swift REPL and is largely used for Swift on Server apps.  As such, we can build apps without knowing about or using the tools regularly in mobile app development. We use `xcodebuild` and `xcrun` under the hood interacting with Xcode even though we don't realise it because they're bundled in [Xcode's Command Line tools](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html) (documentation archive, but still relevant).

`fastlane` is an example CI tool that automates the build process, certificate signing, and interfacing with App Store Connect, using these tools.

## xcodebuild

`xcodebuild` is part of Xcode's bundled command-line tools package. From the [manpages](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xcodebuild/):

> build Xcode projects and workspaces
>
> xcodebuild builds one or more targets contained in an Xcode project,
> or builds a scheme contained in an Xcode workspace or Xcode project.

`xcodebuild` has lots of options and use cases. The options are equivalent to certain user actions within the Xcode IDE. Example usage:

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme MyScheme
```

> Builds the scheme MyScheme in the Xcode workspace MyWorkspace.xcworkspace.

In the command above, we build the workspace without Xcode, using what Xcode runs internally for compilation. Xcode can only be installed on macOS and we have the same limitations for using its command-line tools, including `xcodebuild` and `xcrun`.

## xcrun

`xcrun` is another Xcode command-line tool part of Xcode's CLI tools. From the [manpages](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xcrun/):

> run or locate development tools
>
> `xcrun` provides a means to locate or invoke coexistence- and
> platform-aware developer tools from the command-line, without
> requiring users to modify makefiles or otherwise take inconvenient
> measures to support multiple Xcode toolchains.

```
xcrun [-sdk SDK] -find <tool_name>
```

`xcrun` is also commonly used with `Xcode-select` to manage multiple Xcode versions on the same machine. Every version of Xcode comes bundled with its own development tools, and we can use `xcrun` to get the current path to them:

```
xcrun xcode-select --print-path
```

## swift

`swift` is the Swift REPL. `swift` is a command-line tool that includes the Swift toolchain but can also be installed outside of the Xcode bundled tools. `swift` is different from `xcodebuild` and `xcrun` because it is compiled Swift rather than C. `swift` is not well documented in the MacOS [manpages](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/swift/) documentation, however, Apple has documented these tools on its [blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=18):

> Xcode 6.1 introduces yet another way to experiment with Swift in the
> form of an interactive Read Eval Print Loop, or REPL.

A [REPL](https://www.nickang.com/2020-01-06-what-is-repl/) is essentially an interactive compilation environment or shell. First, the REPL reads code, then evaluates it, prints, and repeats the process. As you can imagine, there is much less we can develop using a REPL compared to an IDE. However, there are other use cases for Swift than iOS, watchOS, and macOS development.

`swift` includes the [standard library](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift) and doesn't include libraries such as `Foundation` and `UIKit`. These Swift libraries are almost certainly needed for iOS or macOS development, so we can't develop apps using the `swift` REPL alone. However, Swift on Server projects regularly use `swift` to run Swift code on Linux and even [Windows](https://swift.org/blog/swift-on-windows/) machines.

For wider adoption, Apple has made `swift` available on different Operating Systems where Xcode is not readily available. Swift now also has [Docker support](https://hub.docker.com/_/swift/) and Windows. Docker enables us to run `swift` on any machine regardless of the underlying OS. `swift` in these applications serves as a *scripting* language.

### Bonus notes for SoS

`swift` is used largely for [Swift on Server](https://swift.org/server/). Swift on Server has great performance for server applications, with a lower memory footprint, fast startup time, and deterministic performance. Although it is not quite as fast as .NET core for some tasks, this is because Swift is much safer with a rigorous type system, garbage collection with ARC, and fewer optimisations for server-specific apps. Many early adopters praise the improved language type system, memory efficiency, and algorithmic performance. In fact, Swift vapor is [comparable to Python](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r20&hw=ph&test=json&l=v2qha7-sf) and Ruby in efficiency for JSON Serialization tasks. Swift is comparable to Java in very few tasks, but this is likely to change as the language and ecosystem grow.

Comment: Thanks for the nice write up. Only thing is about your SoS notes: ARC is not garbage collection. From the SoS link you provide there is this sentence "Swift’s use of ARC (instead of tracing garbage collection)..."

Comment: Nope. ARC is a form of garbage collection. Tracing garbage collection is different. See: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/285333/how-does-garbage-collection-compare-to-reference-counting

Answer (score 3):

### xcrun

Think of `xcrun` as a *convenience prefix* to invoke various command line tools *in the currently active* Xcode toolchain.

Multiple Xcode toolchains can be installed on the same machine (e.g. latest release, beta release and/or legacy releases). Use `xcode-select` to set which Xcode toolchain path is used.  Alternately, the active developer toolchain can be specified by setting the environment variables `SDKROOT` and `DEVELOPER_DIR`

```bash
### open 'bin' directory for the currently active Xcode toolchain 
open `xcode-select --print-path`/usr/bin
```

Tools which can be invoked with `xcrun` include:

- `xcrun simctl <subcommand>` ~ iOS Simulator Control
- `xcrun xcodebuild …` ~ build/test Xcode projects and workspaces
- `xcrun xctrack <commands> [options]` ~ record, import and export Instruments .trace files

```bash
xcrun not_a_tool  help

# xcrun: error: 
#   sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/…/bin/xcodebuild 
#         -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/…/MacOSX.sdk 
#         -find not_a_tool 2> /dev/null' 
# failed with exit code 17664: (null) (errno=Invalid argument)
```

### xcodebuild

Think of `xcodebuild` as single command line tool specialized to *harness multiple other tools to manage an overall project build process*. An invocation of `xcodebuild` will execute many tasks just like `Build` or `Test` in the Xcode GUI menus do when creating and/or testing a project.

```bash
xcodebuild -help
```

Note: `xcodebuild` can be invoked without a proceeding `xcrun`.

```bash
xcrun xcodebuild -version
# Xcode 13.2.1
# Build version 13C100

xcodebuild -version 
# Xcode 13.2.1
# Build version 13C100
```

### swift

Think of `swift` (by itself) as the interpreted, interactive, scriptable, "REPL" version of the `swiftc` compiler.

Then, expand the scope to think of `swift` as a basis for a extended ecosystem which does not require the presence of Xcode (unless an AppleOS SDK is needed to target Apple hardware).

```bash
swift --help

# SUBCOMMANDS (swift <subcommand> [arguments]):
#   build:   SwiftPM - Build sources into binary products
#   package: SwiftPM - Perform operations on Swift packages
#   run:     SwiftPM - Build and run an executable product
#   test:    SwiftPM - Build and run tests
```

*Command Line Example*

```bash
> swift
Welcome to Swift version 5.5.2-dev.
Type :help for assistance.
  1> 8 + 9 
$R0: Int = 17
  2> :quit
```

> Note: [Swift REPL works in conjuction with the LLDB debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777110/how-do-i-quit-swift-repl-without-using-ctrl-d/33818839#33818839), thus `:` preceeds commands like `help` and `quit` during the REPL session.

*Swift Script Example*

Script `example_script.swift` File:

```swift
#!/usr/bin/swift

// File: example_script.swift
// reminder: chmod to executable before invoking the script

import Foundation

func printHelp() {
    print("Please add an argument to the command line. Thanks.")
}

// --- main ---
if CommandLine.argc < 2 {
    printHelp()
} else {
    for i: Int in 1 ..< Int(CommandLine.argc) {
        print( CommandLine.arguments[i] )
    }
}
```

Interpretated and Compiled Script Execution:

```bash
ls -l example_script.swift 
# -rwxr--r--@ 1 user staff  321 Dec 30 16:56 example_script.swift

./example_script.swift 
# Please add an argument to the command line. Thanks.

./example_script.swift a bcd
# a
# bcd

## Let's compile the script...
swiftc example_script.swift 

ls -l ex*
# -rwxr-xr-x  1 user staff  55136 Dec 30 16:57 example_script
# -rwxr--r--  1 user staff    321 Dec 30 16:56 example_script.swift

./example_script
# Please add an argument to the command line. Thanks.

./example_script xyx
# xyz
```

---

REPL: Read Evaluate Print Loop