# How to generate an iOS build for a flutter app using Android Studio?

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a Mac but for some complex reasons that is not worth explaining here, I will be not be able to install xCode. I have checked the tutorial [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/macos), where they provide two options. In both options, XCode is used. My question is: Is it possible to generate a build for iOS on a Mac without using XCode.

Comment: not possible. you will need xcode

Comment: You can only generate de build using xCode.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to do this in Android Studio. If you don't have a machine with macOS (or are not able to use XCode in your case), you might be able to make a build using a macOS [docker](https://www.docker.com/) image.

You can find a [macOS docker image (Docker-OSX) here](https://github.com/sickcodes/Docker-OSX) (200k downloads). On this page, you can also find [container images with XCode installed](https://github.com/sickcodes/Docker-OSX#container-images).

If you don't want to use the XCode app('s GUI) on your machine (or when using this Docker image), but you do have XCode (and [Command Line Tools](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=command%20line%20tools)) installed - you can also make a build via the terminal using the `xcodebuild` command: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html

For more on `xcodebuild`, see this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69030619/6937779).

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not.

What you can do though is use an external tool like [Odevio](https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI) which will let you have access to a Mac build machine with XCode installed.

Then you can generate an IPA like this:

```
odevio build start --build-type ad-hoc
odevio build ipa
```

Here is [Odevio 's documentation](https://odevio-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)